# Eloquent sorting based on column value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a product price table with following columns

```
product_id, seller_id, original_price, sale_price, sale_start_date, sale_end_date
```

i want to sort the table to effective price in asc.

Effective price can be original_price or sale_price if its not zero and the current date is between start and end date.

If any one have a solution, kindly explain the solution as i am not very strong in sql and is trying to learn

Comment: Maybe you can solve it with a sub select, but probably won't be efficient on a large dataset. Maybe you can create a third column: current_price, or just price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by selecting `effective_price` as an aggregate and ordering by it. For example:

```sql
select
    *,
    if (
        sale_price > 0 and sale_start_date <= now() and sale_end_date > now(),
        sale_price,
        original_price
    ) as effective_price
from product_price
order by effective_price asc
```

Or via eloquent:

```php
ProductPrice::selectRaw('
    *,
    if (
        sale_price > 0 and sale_start_date <= now() and sale_end_date > now(),
        sale_price,
        original_price
    ) as effective_price
')->orderBy('effective_price')->get();
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. Can you check Elias comment on the question